# Parse avsc file to get key value pairs in desired format

Tags: json

I have a `.avsc` file that has data in `json` format like below

```
{
"type":"records",
"name": "settings_table",
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "testing_value",
        "default":null,
        "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "description",
        "default":null,
        "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "key_value",
        "default":null,
        "type": [
        "null",
        "long"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create a file that has the output like below

```
testing_value  string
description string
key_value long
```

I have tried like below in `Linux`

```
cat file_name.avsc | python -m json.tool > temp_file_name.avsc

sed -i 's/\"//g;s/\,//g' temp_file_name.avsc

grep name temp_file_name.avsc|cut -d':' -f2|tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" > new_file_after_parsing.txt
```

The result I got is below

```
testing_value
description
key_value
```

Comment: Not quite JSON since type and name are missing commas after each and there's an extra comma after the `key_value` object.

Comment: @Tanktalus Sorry copy paste issue corrected now Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to use `jq`:

```
 jq '.fields[] | "\(.name) \(.type[1])" ' x.avcs | xargs -n1 echo
```

That is, loop through your `fields` array, pull create a string of its name and second item in the type list, and then use `echo` to print it out without the quotes.

I'm sure there are edge cases for this code, but I don't know if you'll hit them.